# Fetching all records from Postgres using Golang webform when no filter is applied i.e empty 'Where' clause

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a Golang function to fetch all the records from Postgres database, this function is simply using :

`SELECT * from stock_transactions`
I want to apply filter to this function to fetch records with some conditions, in-short I want to use :

`SELECT * from stock_transactions WHERE symbol = $symb`

The problem is to handle the case where if `$symb = null` the query should act as `SELECT * from stock_transactions`. I can write an `if-else` clause for the same but if the number of parameters are more than 2 it could be messy. Is there a better way to handle this?

My function:

```
func showstocks (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    var err error

if r.Method != "GET" {
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    return
}

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM stock_transaction ORDER BY id DESC")
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
    return
}
defer rows.Close()

sks := make([]stockdata, 0)


for rows.Next() {
    sk := stockdata{}
    err := rows.Scan(&sk.Sname, &sk.Ttype, &sk.Uprice, &sk.Qty, &sk.Bfee, &sk.Ddate) 
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
        return
    }
    sks = append(sks, sk)
}
if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
    return
}

tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "dashboard.gohtml", sks)
```

}

Comment: `WHERE (foo = $1 OR $1 IS NULL) AND (bar = $2 OR $2 IS NULL) ...`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and share my comment.

Comment: What if you want to actually generate `WHERE symbol is NULL`?  Or is that something you do not need to support?

Comment: @mkopriva, Used as suggested but it is showing no records when passed stock_symbol as null in the form`rows, err := db.Query("SELECT stock_symbol,transaction_type,price,quantity, total_brokerage,txn_date FROM stock_transaction where (stock_symbol = $1 OR $1 IS NULL) ORDER BY id DESC", stock_symbol)`

Comment: @jjanes, in my case it won't happen as the column 'symbol' is NOT NULL type so it can never have null values.

Comment: @RockyPareek how did you pass null? what is the value of the `stock_symbol` Go variable passed into `db.Query`?

Comment: @mkopriva, I want the query to return all the rows from DB if nothing is passed in 'foo' and 'bar' which'll be the default state. further should return filtered results only if something is passed in 'foo'.

Comment: @mkopriva, will pass null for `stock_symbol` from the UI, a web form. I am collecting the FormValue and passing it to the query.

Comment: @RockyPareek the question is about how you're representing null in Go, i.e. is it a string, like `"null"`? because that's not equivalent to postgres' `NULL`. So please can you be more specific, what is it that you're actually passing to the database?

Comment: Basically if you want to tell the database that one of the arguments is `NULL` you have to pass a Go `nil`. You cannot pass `"null"`, nor `"NULL"`, nor `"nil"`, these are all Go strings, and they will be turned to postgres string values, valid values, `NULL` is *not* a value.

Comment: @mkopriva, I am collecting the value for `stock_symbol` like this : `stock_symbol := r.FormValue("stock_symbol")`. If user submits the form without any value for `stock_symbol' it will recieve `stock_symbol as"" empty string. Let me know if that answers your question, Thanks!

Comment: @RockyPareek yes that answers my question. To be able to pass `nil` or some valid string, if one was provided, you have to do something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/8h2dnQvfWFZ

Comment: WOW!!!.. That WORKED!!! @mkopriva, You are a true GENIUS, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Suggested by @mkopriva. Tried and tested.

package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // ...

```
// use interface{} because string types cannot be nil
var stock_symbol interface{} // the "zero-value of interface types is nil, so stock_symbol here is nil

// if empty then stock_symbol will be left as nil
if val := r.FormValue("stock_symbol"); len(val) > 0 {
    stock_symbol = val // set to the provided value
}

// ...

// now stock_symbol is either the provided string value or nil
db.Query("SELECT ... WHERE (stock_symbol = $1 OR $1 IS NULL)", stock_symbol)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `(stock_symbol = $1 OR $1 IS NULL)` trick as you have already seen, which is programmatically convenient.  However this can often lead to inefficient queries, as the query planner may not be smart enough to optimize them correctly.  It might be better to write some code which removes the tautological phrases and also removes the corresponding bind variables, rather than passing each of them to the database.  It is slightly messy, but it should be encapsulated into a function, not rewritten each time.